# Почему свойство margin: auto исторически не работает по вертикали?

Tags: css, позиционирование, спецификация

Всех приветствую!

Вопрос скорее теоретический, чем практический. Понятное дело, что существует большое количество способов отцентровать объект по вертикали, начиная от абсолютного позиционирования, заканчивая флексами, гридами и т.д. Но у меня вопрос, как так произошло, что настолько удобный в перспективе способ не работает испокон веку? Может же блок вычислить отступы, с помощью флексов тех-же, т.е. это уже написанная, оптимизированная формула, которую можно было бы отнести и к margin'у, но этого до сих пор не происходит, даже в тестовом режиме.

Подскажите, может можно где-то почитать об этом, если такая сложность возникает из-за какой-то особенности блочной модели, например? И вообще, есть ли шанс что такое свойство будет добавлено в будущем?

Всем добра!

Comment: [Why does margin: auto only work horizontally and not vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8620200/2881286)

Comment: `auto` для `margin-top` и `margin-bottom` вычисляется как 0. https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-margin-auto/

Comment: Для вертикального выравнивания нужна соответствующая ось направления потока. В обычной блочно-строчной модели поток идёт слева направо и просто переносится на новую строку при переполнении контейнера. Поэтому там margin: auto выравнивает только по горизонтали. А вот во флексах появляется вертикальная ось, вдоль которой с помощью margin: auto можно выровнять элемент. Только надо помнить, что у родителя должна быть задана определённая высота (некоторые ошибочно полагают, что вертикальное выравнивание не работает, забывая, что должно быть пространство для такого выравнивания).